# How can I convert json string to google.visualization.DataTable?

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I am getting a json string from the response. How can I create a data table from that?

e.g.

```
var jasonString = "..........";

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jasonString);
```

Comment: is the JSON really ".........." ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the function [arrayToDataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable)

```
var jsonString = ".........."; // json string of array
var array  = JSON.parse(jsonString);

var dataTableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);

// use dataTableData to build dataTable
```

Comment: This is only for a very special case of JSON string.  If you have a random JSON object and you'd like to show it in a DataTable, then convert to an array first.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-javascript-object-with-numeric-keys-into-array

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example) it says you can just put the JSON response directly into `google.visualization.DataTable`

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

Comment: Note that the JSON has to be correctly [formatted](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) with `cols` and `rows` arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['line'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var json = $.ajax({
        url: "GetFaturamentoMes",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonData) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('number', 'Mês');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Faturamento Por Mês');

            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                mes = jsonData[i].Mes;
                total = jsonData[i].Total;
                data.addRow([mes, total]);
            }
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'Gráfico de Faturamento Mensal',
                    subtitle: 'Moeda (R$)'
                },
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                axes: {
                    x: {
                        10: { side: 'top' }
                    }
                }
            };
            var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));
            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
        }
    });
}
```