# Convert an output in JSON to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, json

I have an Output in JSON like this. I now have to use this data for the regression line
 fitting.

```
[{"year":"1995","values":"46.8550182"},{"year":"1996","values":"47.1409752"},                   {"year":"1997","values":"46.6331669"},{"year":"1998","values":"46.3054604"]
```

Initially, I did this small project with the data inside the same module which was like this.

```
var data = [

            [1995, 46.85],
            [1996, 47.14],
            [1997, 46.63],
            [1998, 46.31],
            [1999, 45.50],
            [2000, 46.09],]
```

Now I want to take data from the JSON file and use that data for the regression line fitting. How can I do that ? Would you please help me ?

Comment: look at [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for starters.

Comment: duplicate question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array

Comment: @ Limbenjamin, I tried the first answer on the top but it too didn't work for me.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Parsing the JSON? Iterating over an array? Accessing properties of an object? Creating  a new array? Adding elements to an array? Something else? Those are all really basic things. If you read the MDN javascript guide, you will learn about these things: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: I'm having problem creating a new array. I want to create a new array like just like the second one ( var data =[[1995, 46.85],
            [1996, 47.14]) from the data in JSON format.

Comment: Creating a new array is as simple as `var newArray = [];`. Then you can add elements with `newArray.push(value);`. FYI, the steps I listed above is one way to convert the input array into the output array. So if you know all of things, you should be able to achieve your goal following those steps.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/qkox62z5/

Uses map and assumes data is coming in as an array already so youd need to use JSON.parse on the json string from where it comes from

```
function format( jsonData ){
    return jsonData.map( function( item ){ return[ item.year, item.values] });
}
```

Usage is like...

```
format( JSON.parse( jsonString ) ) // where jsonString is your response from the json file
```

Comment: Thank you Scott for your kind response. But sorry, it didn't work for me.

Comment: What didnt work about it? Are you having trouble of placing in your code or what?

Comment: Yaa Scott. I'm having trouble of placing that in my code.

Comment: I just copy pasted the code you wrote and just changed jsonData to data. Did I do a blunder ?

Comment: Is the data an array of objects already? or is it the JSON string. If its the JSON string you need to JSON.parse( data ) to get it into an array of objects. Then you would call format() on that and set it to a variable which will then be useable like you had before.

Comment: Also, instead of calling `format()` on the return value of `JSON.parse()`, you can just pass it as its second argument.