# convert json object to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

After a mysql query, I used the json_encode to convert the result of the query and I'm getting the following:

```
[
    {"id":"1","map_id":"1","description":"This is Athens","lat":"37.77994127700315","lng":"23.665237426757812","title":"Athens"},
    {"id":"2","map_id":"1","description":"This is Rome","lat":"41.9100711","lng":"12.5359979","title":"Rome"}
]
```

I want to convert this to JavaScript array but getting only the values. For example:

```
myArray = [  
    [1, 1, 'This is Athens', 37.77994127700315,23.665237426757812, 'Athens']
    [2, 1, 'This is Rome', 41.9100711, 12.5359979, 'Rome']
]
```

I tried many solutions I found here, but I didn't found any solution to give me exactly an array like `myArray`.

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You could take a look in http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: I tried solutions that I found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array and in some other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming :

```
var a = [{"id":"1","map_id":"1","description":"This is Athens","lat":"37.77994127700315","lng":"23.665237426757812","title":"Athens"},{"id":"2","map_id":"1","description":"This is Rome","lat":"41.9100711","lng":"12.5359979","title":"Rome"}];
```

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var myArray = a.map(function(e){
    return [e.id, e.map_id, e.description, e.lat, e.lng, e.title];
});
```

Result:

```
[
  ["1","1","This is Athens","37.77994127700315","23.665237426757812","Athens"],
  ["2","1","This is Rome","41.9100711","12.5359979","Rome"]
]
```

Comment: How can I check the contents of myArray? I used alert(JSON.stringify(myArray)). Is this right?

Comment: Yea, that works, although I prefer using the developer console with `console.log(myArray)`

Comment: I'm getting the following error : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for line var myArray = a.map(function(e){

Comment: So, @MariaKypr, did this help you?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately this returns a result 
["1","1","This is Athens","37.77994127700315","23.665237426757812","Athens","2","1","This is Rome","41.9100711","12.5359979","Rome"]. It results in array with one row.

Comment: Eh, no, it doesn't. I added the result to my answer. You are probably overlooking some brackets. In fact, the result you describe can't possibly be the result from my code.

Comment: I found what was wrong. In my code, I used jQuery ajax to make a call to php function. The php function results to the json_encode and it was returned to ajax from "success" parameter. The result was returned as a string, not as an object. I used JSON.parse() to convert it to json object and now it's working! :) Thank you!! :)