# convert json object to serialized string for server side processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert a returned json object into a serialized string that I can process further with some PHP server side code:

The returned object looks like this:

```
Object {id: "123456787654321", email: "some-email@gmail.com", first_name:   "First", gender: "male", last_name: "Last"}
```

I can convert the object to a string with the following:

```
var paramString = JSON.stringify(response);
console.log(paramString);

// doesn't work
//var params = paramString.serialize();
```

***How do I now convert the string to a serialized string*** that I can pass to my server with the following client side call:

I would expect something like this:

```
id=123456787654321&email=some-email@gmail.com&first_name...
```

My server side code:

```
$.post("/functions/test_functions.php", {params: params}, function(data) {
    ...                             
}, "json");
```

I handle the params array like this server side:

```
$vars = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET" ? $_GET : $_POST; 

$params = array();
isset($vars['params']) ? parse_str($vars['params'], $params) : null;
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(paramString)`?

Comment: RGraham...I think that converts it back to an object

Comment: I see what you mean. You're really asking how to [convert an Object to an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to convert an object to a serialized string (e.g. id=12345654321&email=some-email@gmail.com&first_name....)

Comment: If that's the case, look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: @Max That was the answer...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass JSON-string to server and decode it with json_decode(). See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for details.

Comment: I don't want to introduce another decoding method server side for my params string.  All my other functions pass a serialized string that I can parse into an array

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a specific reason for stringifying, you don't actually need to. jQuery [.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) will handle the serialization for you, for example:

```
var response = {id: "123456787654321", email: "some-email@gmail.com", first_name:   "First", gender: "male", last_name: "Last"};
$.post("/functions/test_functions.php", response, function(data) {
    ...                             
}, "json");
```

Will make a POST request like this:

*/functions/test_functions.php*
**Content-Type:** application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
**Form Data:** id=12345654321&email=some-email@gmail.com&first_name....