# Send an array from node server to js script

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, json, node.js

My server (node.js) maintains an array :

```
var list = [];
```

I want to use this array in some js code (client side). I would like to retrieve it thanks to ajax. What is the best practice?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/updatePendingAlerts",
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function (data)  {
      console.log(data);
      //data should be an array

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      clearInterval(timeout);
      alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
```

Comment: In express you could do res.send(JSON.stringify(list));

Comment: is this the best practice thought?

Comment: Check there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array

Comment: Set headers as mentioned in Quetin's answer and then i think it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialise it to JSON (with `JSON.stringify`) and output it with an `application/json` content-type header.

It will then be an array in `data` with the client side JavaScript you already have.

Comment: thank that worked. I was just wondering if had no other options then using json.

Comment: There are lots of options. JSON is just simplest and easiest since JS speaks it natively and it maps directly onto JS data types.