# how to add JSON output in jquery array

Tags: jquery, json

how to add below json in jquery array

```
{hirierchy_add={32=a, 33=b}, events={42=dd, 43=bsfs}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse()` to that job

```
var x = JSON.parse(your_json_string);
var sampleArray = []; //create a sample array
for(var data in x){
  arr.push(parsed[data]); //push the datas in the array
}
```