# Change array to object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to change an array into an object using javascript

For an example.
I have an array which looks like :

```
colours [        
["black","red",shades : ["0","1","2"]]        
]
```

I want to change this to :

```
colours [
    {
    "black","red", shades : ["0","1","2"]
    }
]
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can do this using javascript code.

Comment: ["black","red",shades:["0","1","2"]] this is not a valid array. arrays dont have defined keys in js, only object

Comment: Neither the object is a valid one ...

Comment: Check out [what an object looks like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [what an array looks like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray), and tell us why you want to do this.

Comment: i am sorry for the confusion. I am a beginner. What i want to do it to make JSON object. colours [
    {
    "black","red", shades : ["0","1","2"]
    }
] will that be correct?

Comment: @qualitytest That's not correct. Check out the links above.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that will not be correct. You need to post what you actually have. You don't have the things you posted because they cannot exist.

Comment: I am afraid it is difficult to share entire code. I can show the browser debug content. what i have currently is this 0: Array[0]
prop1: Object
prop2: Array[40]
descriptor: Array[0]
prop3: Array[10]
prop4: Array[1]
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0] what i want to change to is this 0: Object
prop1: Object
prop2: Array[40]
descriptor: Array[0]
prop3: Array[10]
prop4: Array[1]
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: Why don't express your object as `{colors: ["black","red"], shades:["0","1","2"]}` ? Your sample object notation doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function toObject(arr) {
 var rv = {};
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
  rv[i] = arr[i];
 return rv;
}
```

Try to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = $.map(obj, function(el) { return el; });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/)

This question is been asked.

[Here's the full details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)

Comment: This answers how to convert an object to array. I want to do it the other way round. I want to convert an array to object. Can you please help