# Want to show image icon in the list view using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, url

I have been trying to show a list view of users with their profile picture in a table. I can show the picture as a url (fetched from database), but would like to show the real image icon instead. Below is the screenshot of what I am getting right now.
[image: image with URL]
I would like to show the real image instead of the URL. 
I am using javascript for this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `<img src='+yourPath+'>` ?

Comment: For getting those values in the table, I am using Bootstrap table.            <table class="table-bodered" data-classes="table table-hover table-condensed" data-toggle="table" data-url="http://localhost:1337/users" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-height="600">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="profile_url">Picture</th>
                <th data-field="fullname">Name</th>
                <th data-field="SerialNo">Phone Number</th>
                <th data-field="username">Login ID</th>

Comment: How to use img src there? Thanks for your answer. :) @Rayon Dabre.

Comment: Like this: `<tr><img src='path'></tr>`

Comment: Actually, those <tr> are created dynamically. This uses a script and here is an example.               
                var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');

Comment: Create `img` tag dynamically too and set its `src` attribute...

Comment: o yes! thank you. @Rayon Dabre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check this code. It works fine according to your requirements. You can use database source for Image url. here I am using an array for an example.

```
<body>
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgSrc = new Array ("/tetet/images.png","tetet/images.png");


    for (var i = 0; i < imgSrc.length; i++)
      {
          var node = document.createElement("LI");

          var x = document.createElement("IMG");
          x.setAttribute("src", imgSrc[i]);
          x.setAttribute("width", "304");
          x.setAttribute("width", "228");
          x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
          node.appendChild(x);
          document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
      }  
    </script>
```

Comment: ok. But one more concern. This image src are from a particular URL. I need to parse only the image url from a set of JSON data. Then need to put it in array. Couldn't figure out how to do that. If you can help, that would be a lot for me. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: check this json into javascript array 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array

Comment: then you can easily use an array in your script.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it by the help of the answer given above.

```
var data;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:1337/users",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data); //This is your result 

                console.log(data[1].profile_url);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var node = document.createElement("LI");
                    var x = document.createElement("IMG");

                    x.setAttribute("src", data[1].profile_url);
                    x.setAttribute("width", "304");
                    x.setAttribute("width", "228");
                    x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
                    node.appendChild(x);
                    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please up vote or correct the answer if you think this is helpful for you.