# Convert string csv in JSON to array variable

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have the following JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "Title": "PAGE A",
        "Users": "USRA"
    },
    {
        "Title": "PAGE B",
        "Users": "USRA,USRB"
    }
]
```

What would be the best way to convert the fields with "," in to arrays? and get using javascript:

```
[
    {
        "Title": "PAGE A",
        "Users": "USRA"
    },
    {
        "Title": "PAGE B",
        "Users": ["USRA","USRB"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)

Comment: You would need to make the first Users be `"Users": ["USRA"]`.

Comment: Why on earth would you want an inconsistent data type? Make them all arrays, don't matter if they only have 1 element or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```js
var input = [
        {
            "Title": "PAGE A",
            "Users": "USRA"
        },
        {
            "Title": "PAGE B",
            "Users": "USRA,USRB"
        }
    ];

var output = [];

output = input.map(function(d){
      for (key in d){
        if (d[key].indexOf(',') !== -1){
          d[key] = d[key].split(',');
          }
      } 
     return d;

});

$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(output));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer since it tests the "aaa, bbb" csv issue for all keys.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
data = [
    {
        "Title": "PAGE A",
        "Users": "USRA"
    },
    {
        "Title": "PAGE B",
        "Users": "USRA,USRB"
    }
]

data.forEach(function(item) {
    // the if clause keeps the single user outside of an array
    if (item.Users && item.Users.indexOf(',') >= 0) {
        item.Users = item.Users.split(',');
    }
})
```

In case you wish to keep a consistent data type (make the `Users` property always be an `Array`):

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
    item.Users = item.Users ? item.Users.split(',') : [];
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple for each with a split is all you need

```
var data = [
    {
        "Title": "PAGE A",
        "Users": "USRA"
    },
    {
        "Title": "PAGE B",
        "Users": "USRA,USRB"
    }
];

data.forEach( function (obj) {
    obj.Users = obj.Users.split(",");
});
```

Now if you really do not want that one to be an array, than you need to add an if check.

```
data.forEach( function (obj) {
    var parts = obj.Users.split(",");
    if(parts.length>1) {
        obj.Users = parts;
    }
});
```