# Convert objects to array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I really want to convert a object to array but my codes doesn’t worked.

```
data = "errors": {
  "user": {
    "name": "empty"
  },
  {
    "length": "exceeds"
  },

  "title": {
    "name": "empty"
  },
  {
    "length": "exceeds"
  }
}
```

Now I want to make them:

```
data = ["empty", "exceeds", "empty", "exceeds"];
```

What I’ve done so far is:

```
var arr = Object.keys(data[i].data.errors).map(function(k) {
  return data[i].data.errors[k]
});

console.log(arr);
```

But the output is not what I expected. Please help. Thank very much.

Comment: Please correct the code samples. JS does not support typographical quotes.

Comment: There are more errors than just typographical quotes here. Please have a look at this: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: I just removed now the typographical quotes and changed to "".

Comment: `But the output is not what I expected` - no, you wouldn't be getting **any** output, except errors in the console

Comment: what is that array supposed to represent? what does "empty" mean? It's not clear what your trying to achieve or why.

Comment: Your object notation is invalid.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dznepmox/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you so much. That is what I wanted.

Comment: Here is what it should look like {
 "errors":{
                     "user":{
         "name" : "empty",
                             "length" : "exceeds"
       }, 

                     "title":{
         "name" : "empty",
                              "length" : "exceeds"
        }
             }
      }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1):

If you always know the keys of the inner objects are going to be `name` and `length` a short way might be:

```
var out = Object.keys(data.errors).reduce(function (p, c) {
  return p.concat([data.errors[c].name, data.errors[c].length]);
}, []);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/67mu31zr/)