# D3 get the value in the middle of nested JSON

Tags: json, d3.js, nested

Totally noob question from me. Different from other JSON nested questions, I want to access the value of the middle level.
Consider that I have a JSON like:

```
  "nodes":[
    {"Level1":[
          {"Level2A":[
              {"Level3A":"Value",
               "Level3B":"Value"
              },
              {"Level3A":"Value",
               "Level3B":"Value"
              }]
          },
          {"Level2B":[
              {"Level3A":"Value",
               "Level3B":"Value"
              },
              {"Level3A":"Value",
               "Level3B":"Value"
              }]
           }]    
        }]
```

I want to get the value of Level2 out(to use as label).
I can get lv3 value by calling for example,:

```
node.datum().Level1[0].Level2[0].Level3A
```

but if I tried

```
nodae.datum().Level1[].Level2
```

I get an object instead. The ideal output would be the array with [Level2A, Level2B,...]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your json is in valid mode or you just post half of it?
That what I did-

```
{"nodes":[{"Level1":[{"Level2A":[{"Level3A":"Value","Level3B":"Value"},{"Level3A":"Value",   "Level3B":"Value"}],"Level2B":[{"Level3A":"Value","Level3B":"Value"}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Yeah, there were mistakes. I edited my questions, hope that nothing is wrong

Comment: ok, but you got an object because it is in mode  of json. you can use some function for mapping the object into array like this-Array.map http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array