# store json into an array

Tags: javascript, json

```
[["January 2016", "February 2016", "March 2016", "April 2016", "May 2016", "June 2016"], ["person1", 23274, 24470, 44140, 74651, 42538, 23076], ["person2", 2390, 14333, 9480, 15387, 15006, 4941], ..
```

Hi, how would I go about storing this Json into an array if arrays in Javascript? Not sure how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: That is not valid JSON. It is, in fact, several arrays. Do you want to take those arrays and turn them into JSON or something?

Comment: Possibly   duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array

Comment: Do you really want to store raw unparsed JSON into an array? If we leave JSON apart, do you know how to store e.g. anything else in an array?

Comment: @sbeliv01 It is valid JSON (if you ignore the truncation added by the OP).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're receiving the data as a string, you can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var str = '[["January 2016", "February 2016", "March 2016", "April 2016", "May 2016", "June 2016"], ["person1", 23274, 24470, 44140, 74651, 42538, 23076], ["person2", 2390, 14333, 9480, 15387, 15006, 4941]...';

var myArr = JSON.parse( str );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already a JSON. Example in Javascript:

```
var arrayOfArrays = [["elem1","elem2"], ["elem3","elem4"]]

JSON.stringify(arrayOfArrays) 

response: "[["elem1","elem2"],["elem3","elem4"]]"

JSON.parse('[["elem1","elem2"],["elem3","elem4"]]') 
response: [Array[2], Array[2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse('[["January 2016", "February 2016", "March 2016", "April 2016", "May 2016", "June 2016"], ["person1", 23274, 24470, 44140, 74651, 42538, 23076], ["person2", 2390, 14333, 9480, 15387, 15006, 4941]]')
```