# How to convert json to array in angularjs without keys?

Tags: angularjs

In my code json returning format like this

```
 var data = [
     {"field1":"918666400041","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"},
     {"field1":"918666400035","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"},
     {"field1":"918666400060","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"}
 ];
```

But I need convert to array format with out keys like:

```
 var Data = [
     ['918666400041', '2016-05-19 11:52:52'],
     ['918666400035', '2016-05-19 11:52:52'],
     ['918666400035', '2016-05-19 11:52:52']
 ];
```

Can any one will give solution for this question?

I already tried with `angular.forEach` function and `map` function but I didn't get this format.

Comment: what is the idea behind ignoring the field names of an object? If you want JSON to be like this then you should not have gone for object itself. What you expect is plain array of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 var obj = [ {"field1":"918666400041","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"}, {"field1":"918666400035","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"}, {"field1":"918666400060","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"} ];

var res = obj.map(function(val) {
   return [val.field1, val.field2]
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the browsers you intend to [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=map), you could just use the ES5 [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
var mappedData = data.map(function(obj) { 
    return [obj.field1, obj.field2]; 
});
```

If you don't have access to the ES5 array methods, you could use angular's forEach as follows:

```
var mappedData = [];
angular.forEach(data, function(obj) { 
    mappedData.push([obj.field1, obj.field2]); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var data = [
{"field1":"918666400041","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"},
{"field1":"918666400035","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"},
{"field1":"918666400060","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"}
];

var x =[];

angular.forEach(data,function(val,index){
x.push(val.field1)
x.push(val.field2)
})
```

Now in x you will get required array

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function:

```
var Data = data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    previousValue.push([currentValue.field1, currentValue.field2])
    return previousValue;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can so something like:

```
var l_IN = <your starting JSON> ;

var I_OUT = [] ;

for (x = 0 ; x < l_IN.length ; x++) {

    dummy = {l_IN.field1,l_IN.field2} ;

    l_OUT.push(dummy) ;

// or l_OUT.push(l_IN.field1,l_IN.field2) ;
}

....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var data = [ {"field1":"918666400041","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"},{"field1":"918666400035","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"}, {"field1":"918666400060","field2":"2016-05-19 11:52:52"} ], 
    newData = [];

// Iterating through the data array, to process object by object
for (var i = data.length - 1, tempArray; i >= 0; i--) {
    // returning a new object with only the current object value for each key
    tempArray = Object.keys(data[i]).map(function(k) { return data[i][k] });
    newData.push(tempArray); 
}

console.log(newData);
```

This is quite similar (but a bit more complicated here) than [Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)