# How to read JSON array using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm looking to read JSON array using PHP. I'm using php `file_get_contents` to read the JSON array.

So, here is how my array look like,[image: My array]

Can anyone tell me how can I read all the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

return your array with `json_encode($array)` it will return a JSON Object.

Comment: This is quite literally what JSON was designed to do.

Comment: @Mohamed Nizar, can you explain me specific what did you mean?

Comment: If you read this `file_get_contents('yourfilename.php')` and it should `return json_encode($array)`   you will access your json object

Answer (score 1):

Building on @mohamed-nizar,

**filename.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var json = <?php json_encode(file_get_contents('array.php')); ?>;
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

For converting JSON to and Javascript Array(), check this thread: [How to convert JSON to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array?answertab=votes#tab-top)
But there's really no reason to do so, it's better to just use the JSON.