# How can I check the size of an array containing sub arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sub-array

I want something along the lines of `array1.length` from the below array:

```js
var array1 = {
 sub1: [1,2,3],
 sub2: ["K","J","H"],
 sub3: ["Mango","Armada","Leffen","Mew2king"],
 sub4: ['1/8"', '3/16"', '1/4"'],
};
```

Right now I'm getting the following outputs:

```
console.log(array1) //Object {sub1: Array[3], sub2: Array[3]...}
console.log(array1.length) //undefined
console.log(array1[1]) //undefined
console.log(array1[1].length //Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're not defining an array but an object. array1.sub1.length will give you a length of one of the arrays

Comment: `Object.keys(array1).length` since `array1` is not an array

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thanks, that worked for what I wanted. Is it possible to define an array containing sub arrays?

Comment: @MatthewSirkin yes, rather than creating array1 as an object, you can create an actual array and sub-arrays as the array items

Answer (score 1):

array1 not is a array, is a object. `sub1` and so on are arrays, then you can:

```
array1.sub1.length; // returns 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), not an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

You could iterate over the keys and get the length of the arrays inside of the object.

```js
var object = { sub1: [1, 2, 3], sub2: ["K", "J", "H"], sub3: ["Mango", "Armada", "Leffen", "Mew2king"], sub4: ['1/8"', '3/16"', '1/4"'] };
Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(object[key].length);
});
```

Comment: But Object.keys is not supported in IE8 and below, Opera and FF 3.6 and below.

Comment: you could use [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop with a check for [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
var array1 = {
  sub1: [1, 2, 3],
  sub2: ["K", "J", "H"],
  sub3: ["Mango", "Armada", "Leffen", "Mew2king"],
  sub4: ['1/8"', '3/16"', '1/4"'],
};

console.log(array1.sub1.length,array1.sub2.length,array1.sub3.length,array1.sub4.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like this:

```
var array1 = [[1,2,3],["K","J","H"],["Mango","Armada","Leffen","Mew2king"],
 ['1/8"', '3/16"', '1/4"']];
var flatArray = [].concat.apply([],array1)
```

This will flatten the array so you can use length etc.

Answer (score 0):

See [Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)

```js
var array1 = {
 sub1: [1,2,3],
 sub2: ["K","J","H"],
 sub3: ["Mango","Armada","Leffen","Mew2king"],
 sub4: ['1/8"', '3/16"', '1/4"'],
};
alert("Size : "+Object.keys(array1).map(function(k) { return array1[k] }).length);
```

**OUTPUT**

Size : 4

**HOW IT WORKS**

Converting the keys to an array and then mapping back the values with Array.map
Then, can get the length of this array. Gg wp.

NB : You can also create a var at the beginning and then use it to all your process.

Answer (score -1):

`array1` is a JSON object. So

`array1.subArray.length`

should work

Comment: Unfortunately, it(`array1`) is an object.

Comment: @SankarRaj Thats what I said. `array1` is an object. Don't understand the down vote.