# How can i convert array of objects into key pair value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing messages inside my msges field. This is the format

[image]

I called ajax and it is returning me the data in this format

> [ object, object, object ]

I want to convert it into an array with object keys and object values. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array

Comment: try using forEach, like so: msges.forEach(function(msg) {
     date: { msg.from,.... }
});

Comment: Okay let me try it @JoãoVilaça

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: The image was just to give you all an idea of my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have read values as object

```
//result is the result of the query
    for (var line in result) {
    //acces to uname by line.uname
    //acces to email by line.email
    }
```

Hope that will help you

Or you can use `for each`

```
//result is the result of the query
        for each(line in result) {
        //acces to uname by line.uname
        //acces to email by line.email
        }
```