# Looping Through JSON objects and converting them to arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to build a heatmap using [leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com) and [leaflet.heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat) from data I have in JSON format. So far, I've been able to fetch and parse my JSON file using jQuery's getJSON, but I'm stuck at the part where I loop through the file and return the arrays leaflet.heat needs to build the heatmap layer on top of leaflet.

According to leaflet.heat's documentation, all I need to pass to the library is an array constructed like so:

```
[latitude, longitude, intensity]
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
[{"Lat":"39.51","Long":"-76.164","Intensity":"0.0017980221756068300"},
{"Lat":"39.463","Long":"-76.12","Intensity":"0.0332634102487264000"}, 
...more data...]
```

Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON( 'data.json',
    function(data){
        var heat = L.heatLayer(data, {radius: 25}).addTo(map);
    });
});
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 't.lat')
```

I assume this is resulting from passing a JSON *object* when the library requires an *array* without keys. I've looked at [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array), but when I log the output to the console with this code,

```
var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el });
console.log(arr);
```

...it's still output as an object with keys. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `"Lat" !== "lat"`.

Comment: Surely the array you're trying to build must be 2d to contain the heat data for multiple lat/lng?

Comment: because you are not transforming it.... You are just returning the same exact thing in your map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think should do the trick:

```
var arr = data.map(function(el) {
  return [+el.Lat, +el.Long, +el.Intensity];
});
```

`map` gives you each element of the array one at a time and lets you transform it.

Each element looks like `{"Lat":"39.51","Long":"-76.164","Intensity":"0.0017980221756068300"}`, and you want to transform it to something like `[39.51, -76.164, 0.0017980221756068300]`. You can use `.Lat`, `.Long`, and `.Intensity` to get each of those values, and the preceding `+` converts the values from strings to numbers.

Comment: probably need to coerce to numbers from strings also

Comment: Be aware that `$.map()` will place all the values in a single array with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/h1pf4dwf/. If you want a 2d array, you need to double wrap the output, eg. `[[+el.Lat... ]]`: https://jsfiddle.net/h1pf4dwf/1/. Alternatively you could use the native `map()` function and avoid the problem completely: https://jsfiddle.net/h1pf4dwf/2/

Comment: Wow, what's wrong with `$.map`? I'm at a loss as to how that behavior would help.

Comment: @Jonasw I don't see how `Object.values` would help, since we need to emit the values in the right order.

Comment: Edited to use the native `map`.

Comment: @smarx good point. Would probably work, but i admit that its buggy.

Answer (score -1):

You actually don't need to parse it manually. Modern browsers supports JSON deserialization:

```
var json_string = file.read("filename");
var json_to_array = JSON.parse( json_string );
```