# this.dataObj.push is not a function , getting error while trying to push data in local storage key,value

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to push data in my local storage value, but it is giving me error `this.dataObj.push` is not a function

> Unable to find where i am going wrong, sectionObj, dataObj both are arrays, please advise

`file.ts`

```
myname = '';
sectionObj = [];
getresume = {};
dataObj = [];
data = '';
save() {

    this.sectionObj = [{
        "name": this.myname,
        "contactno": "0",
        "email": "a@a.com"
    }];


    this.data = localStorage.getItem('resume'); //get existing item in localstorage
    if (this.data) //check if it exists or not empty
    {
        this.dataObj = JSON.parse(this.data); //parse string
        this.dataObj.push({
            "name": this.myname,
            "contactno": '2',
            "email": "a@a.com"
        });

    }

    localStorage.setItem("resume", JSON.stringify(this.dataObj));
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `this.data` after reading it from localStorage?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));` ?

Comment: when you do this.dataObj = JSON.parse(this.data); it probably returns something that is NOT an array, that's why you have this issue...

Comment: i am getting this in console `"{\"name\":\"saurabh..\",\"contactno\":\"0\",\"email\":\"a@a.com\"}"`

Comment: Like what @Julo0sS said. The output is not an array it's an object.

Comment: what should be done , please can you mention in code, how can this be corrected

Comment: try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array

Comment: i changed the way it is saved, now is this ok - `"[{\"name\":\"\",\"contactno\":\"0\",\"email\":\"a@a.com\"}]"`