# How to map array into an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How to map array into object in JavaScript?
For example how to map this

```
{
  name: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  uv: [300,-145,-100,-8,100,9],
  pv: [456,230,345,450,312,235]
}
```

into this

```
data = [
  {name: '1', uv: 300, pv: 456},
  {name: '2', uv: -145, pv: 230},
  {name: '3', uv: -100, pv: 345},
  {name: '4', uv: -8, pv: 450},
  {name: '5', uv: 100, pv: 321},
  {name: '6', uv: 9, pv: 235}
]
```

in JavaScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)

Comment: FYI, JSON and JavaScript objects are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#map`

```js
var obj = {
 name:[1,2,3,4,5,6],
 uv:[300,-145,-100,-8,100,9],
 pv:[456,230,345,450,312,235]
};

var result = obj.name.map(function(v,i){
  return {name: v, uv: obj.uv[i], pv: obj.pv[i]};
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow like this:

```js
var first = {
 name:[1,2,3,4,5,6],
 uv:[300,-145,-100,-8,100,9],
 pv:[456,230,345,450,312,235]
}

var data = [];

first.name.forEach((item, i) => {
  data.push({
    name: first.name[i],
    uv: first.uv[i],
    pv: first.pv[i]
  })
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: This will only work when length of name, uv and pv is same. Else we will start getting undefined.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal, yes, but in OP question they have the same length, I wrote this code based on OP's question. If they will have different length, we need to write another code.

Comment: Yes. True! But its better to give generalize approach.. :-D

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the keys and then the properties and assign at each index the wanted values.

This works with an arbitrary count of properties without knowing in advance.

```js
var data = { name: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], uv: [300, -145, -100, -8, 100, 9], pv: [456, 230, 345, 450, 312, 235] },
    result = Object
        .keys(data)
        .reduce((r, k) => (data[k].forEach((v, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || {})[k] = v), r), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```