# How do I sort a json by numeric value?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, numeric, discord.js

How would I go about sorting a json into an array by numeric value and then how would I easily access that information.

```
{"362439239671087109":{"coins":19},"178538363954003968":{"coins":18},"234255082345070592":{"coins":137}}
```

The weird numbers are discord user ids.

Comment: By which numeric value? What have you tried to do?

Comment: That's not an array, it is a dictionary (also called hashmap) - these things can't be sorted. You can convert it into an array - would that help?

Comment: @SQLHacks In JS it's usually called an object.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm. First, make associative array, if the json is generated from bakcend, by example in php, you can use functions for order arrays. ---> http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php
See this:
[Converting JavaScript object with numeric keys into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-javascript-object-with-numeric-keys-into-array)

Comment: Your first link is for PHP, not Javascript. JS doesn't have associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = {"362439239671087109":{"coins":19},"178538363954003968":{"coins":18},"234255082345070592":{"coins":137}};
var b = Object.keys(a);
b.sort(function(x,y){return a[x].coins-a[y].coins});
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Thanks for awnsering so quickly, the json is added to and changed very often, could I instead just call the json file in (var a =)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Perhaps you can edit your question to explan.

Comment: How would I go about reversing this. This currently sorts them from least to most

Comment: If these numbers are going to keep getting big, watch out for exceeding `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.   `9007199254740991`

Comment: **@Nathan**, If someone's answer solved your problem then you should up vote/accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Code that can handle VERY large numbers by treating them as strings.


var a = {
  "362439239671087109": {
    "coins": 19
  },
  "178538363954003968": {
    "coins": 18
  },
  "234255082345070592": {
    "coins": 137
  }
};


function padWithZeros(s) {
  return ("000000000000000000000" + s).substr(-20);
}

var b = Object.keys(a);
b.sort(
  function(x, y) {
    var s1 = padWithZeros(a[x].coins);
    var s2 = padWithZeros(a[y].coins);

    if (s1 === s2) {
      return 0;
    }

    if (s1 > s2) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }


  });
console.log(b);
```