# react .map not allowing me to iterate over object

Tags: reactjs

Here is the component I am building.  I have a dummy backend API that contains a list of fruits, and the response data looks as such:

```
{
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "apple": "Delicious"
    },
    "2": {
      "orange": "It's orange."
    }
  },
  "message": "success retrieved fruits list",
  "status": 200
}
```

Now I am building a component that calls my API (successfully) and I am trying to create a list of the items within data.

```
class FruitList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fruits: {},
            error: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fruitsApi.getFruits()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(
                (results) => {
                    this.setState({
                        fruits: results.data,
                        error: false
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({ error: true });
                    console.log(error);
                }
            )
    }

    getFruits() {
        const items = this.state.fruits.map(
            ([k, v]) => <li key={k}>{v}</li>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <ul>
                        { this.getFruits() }
                    </ul>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default FruitList
```

From this, I result in a `TypeError: this.state.fruits.map is not a function`.  I have tried looking at other examples/errors similar, but can't seem to reason why my case is not acting properly.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: you cant map over an object. From your code , fruits is an object

Comment: So how would one iterate over an object?  It seems all the examples use `.map`

Comment: Well, the error is correct, there's no `map` function on `{
    "1": {
      "apple": "Delicious"
    },
    "2": {
      "orange": "It's orange."
    }
  }`... There would be if it was `[ { "apple": "Delicious" }, { "orange": "It's orange" }]` though...

Comment: How would I pull out the `key`, `value` from this as in python `for k, v in fruits.items()`

Comment: [Converting JavaScript object with numeric keys into array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20881213/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting JavaScript object with numeric keys into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-javascript-object-with-numeric-keys-into-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fruits` is an object, not an array, the method `map` only exists natively on the array type in JavaScript.

To iterate over the key value pairs of fruits you can do either of the following:

```js
getFruits() {
    const items = Object.keys(this.state.fruits).map(
        (key) => <li key={key}>{this.state.fruits[key]}</li>
    );
}
```

or

```js
getFruits() {
    const items = Object.entries(this.state.fruits).map(
        ([key, value]) => <li key={key}>{value}</li>
    );
}
```

Comment: I included a `return items` statement.. Now, I reach this error: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {orange}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: This is because in the example above your json has the keys `1` and `2` so when doing:

`Object.entries(this.state.fruits).map(([key, value]) =>`
the key will be `1` and the value will be `{ "apple": "Delicious" }` which is still an object, and react throws an error here.

I'm not sure how you want to use your data but I think that if you're going to use an object structure for your api response it makes more sense to use this for `data`:

`{
  "apple": "delicious",
  "orange": "It's orange"
}`
vs maintaining indeces as object keys. Or use an actual array.

Comment: I want to hold integrity of the order, I know that this can be done in a list but for my use case holding the `1` is valuable.  I am just putting together a dummified code example... how can I access the nested structure of `value` in the example above?

Comment: Arrays will hold the index of the order for you as well. If your data was: `[{  "apple": "Delicious" }, { "orange": "It's orange." }]` and you did `fruits.forEach((fruit, idx) => ...))` the second argument of for each, `idx` would give you either the 1 or the 2 and this makes it simpler to add / remove data since the array maintains the numbers for you. It's important to think of how to structure the data that you're sending to the frontend, not just how to access it once it's there.

Comment: Additionally, there's no easy answer to the how to access the value problem, since your keys aren't predictable - i.e. the key is the name of the fruit. If you structure your data like: `[{  "name": "apple", "description": "Delicious" }, {  "name": "orange", "description": "It's orange." }]` then the keys are *serialized, i.e. predictable, and you can use the following:
`fruits.forEach((fruit, idx) => <li key={fruit.name}>{fruit.name}: {fruit.description}</li>))` which is far cleaner, and which is what I'm guessing you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to to something like this :

`Array.from(this.state.fruits).map(...)`

It will change your object to an array. Take a look at `Object.values` that would work as well

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it using the Object.values

```
const data = {
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "apple": "Delicious"
    },
    "2": {
      "orange": "It's orange."
    }
  },
  "message": "success retrieved fruits list",
  "status": 200
}

const fruits = data.data;
const list = Object.values(fruits);

console.log(list)
```

Comment: Now when rendering, I error out with: `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`