# How do I convert a JSON file to a JS array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an API key from [Forecast.io](http://Forecast.io) that gives me the JSON output found in the file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-onvFkia1zabFFSd1A2WjN1MHM/view?usp=sharing).  I would like to create a plot of some of the data included (e.g. the variation of temperature over a period of time).  Once I get the data into a JavaScript array, I plan on using the [Google Charts API](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) to create the chart, but I'm struggling to figure out what the best way to efficiently convert the JSON data to a JavaScript array.

Looking around on various forums, several places reference that they are using jQuery.  Is that a necessity?  If so, can you point me toward a good tutorial for getting that setup?

P.S. If you can't tell, I'm very much a newbie at this, so please excuse my very rudimentary knowledge of what I'm doing.

Comment: This may be a possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896219/how-can-i-convert-json-string-to-google-visualization-datatable

Comment: What is a "JavaScript table"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the JSON directly to a variable, without the need of an array:

```
var json_object = your_raw_json;
```

Then you could use the json object to populate the rows on the chart.
Here is an example that uses the "ApparentTempMax" from the JSON you provided:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'ApparentTempMax');

    //WHERE THE DATA IS BEING SET: START

    var rows = new Array;

    var daily_weather_data = json_object.daily.data;
    for(var i=0; i<daily_weather_data.length; i++){
        var day_data = daily_weather_data[i];
        rows.push([i, day_data.apparentTemperatureMax]);
    }

    /*
     At this point rows will look like this:
     [
        [0, 74.24], [1, 68.1], [2, 77.03], [3, 77.68],
        [4, 78.5], [5, 80.36], [6, 87.44], [7, 89.94]
     ]
    */

    data.addRows(rows);

    //WHERE THE DATA IS BEING SET: END

    var options = {
       hAxis: {
          title: 'Day'
       },
       vAxis: {
         title: 'ApparentTempMax'
       }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

**FUNCTIONING EXAMPLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/6qpf7tek/2/

Answer (score -1):

**definition of JSON:**

> JSON is similar to JavaScript’s way of writing arrays and objects, with a few restrictions. All property names have to be surrounded by double quotes, and only simple data expressions are allowed—no function calls, variables, or anything that involves actual computation. Comments are not allowed in JSON.

[here's an excellent learning  ref.](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#h_AxpOdvCznQ)

In JS to get data from and to JSON you have two specific methods JSON.stringify() and [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

*Your first step would then be to parse the Json data*

```
var forecast = JSON.parse(YOUR_FILE)
```

Then from here you can achieve anything with methods and functions, I suggest you stick with JS because that's how your object is stored (or jquery);

Comment: Don't forget to add a [ before and a ] after the data since it is an Array.  Otherwise the parse will probably fail.

Comment: actually I tried parsing this json in local file.. but the output  looks correct , where would you put the square brackets?

Comment: I know how JSONs work and how to get them into the JavaScript. I'm mainly asking about whether there is a more efficient means to collect all the entries for a specific key into an array.

Comment: To be clear, I know how to get the data into my script, but I'm not sure what to do with it once it's there.