# How to pass string data from pandas dataframe to a google.visualization.DataTable using json and flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, google-visualization

I'm trying to build a wordtree data visualisation website element using [google word trees](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/wordtree), and `flask`.

The approach I've taken is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896219/how-can-i-convert-json-string-to-google-visualization-datatable) answer, including attempting to implement the formatting recommended [here](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-python/blob/master/examples/static_example.py), and I've also tried following [this](http://www.banjolanddesign.com/flask-google-charts.html) tutorial, but my `word_trees.html` just keeps rendering a blank page.

Apart from the data loading from a much larger, though equivalent `.csv` in the actual application, the relevant parts of `app.py` are:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pandas as pd
import gviz_api

#create to data
lst = ["You've stolen a 'PIZZA' my heart! @CfgLaw Than",
       "Did your workplace buy you pizza for #national",
       "So last week on #NationalPizzaDay I had plans|",
       "Last week it was #NewStartersDay and #National",
       "@JurysInnsHotels #NationalPizzaDay Wow! I’m dr"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':lst})

#initiate app
app = Flask(__name__)

#create gvis formatted data
def get_data():
  # Creating the data
  description = {"text": ("string", "Text")}
  data = [{"text":"{}".format(text)} for text in df.text]
  # Loading it into gviz_api.DataTable
  data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(description)
  data_table.LoadData(data)
  # Creating a JSon string
  json_string = data_table.ToJSon()
  return json_string

#pass data to template 
@app.route("/")
def word_trees():
    data = get_data()
    return render_template('word_trees.html',tweets=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And `word_trees.html` is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages:['wordtree']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(tweets);
        );

        var options = {
          wordtree: {
            format: 'implicit',
            word: 'pizza',
            type: 'double'
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.WordTree(document.getElementById('wordtree_basic'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wordtree_basic" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect the app to render a wordtree based on the data in `df.text`, but it keeps rending a blank page.

Comment: The reason I didn't use the `%(tweets)s` syntax, is that the github example doesn't use flask, or an external html template. It rather loads a string from within python. I'm trying to structure the app using `flask` conventions, so want to pass the json to my html from python, rather than past the html into my python script.

Comment: maybe try --> `{{tweets}}`